# Website Title Change why not working on Facebook?

Tags: html, facebook, title

I want to share my website on my facebook status. But when I write www.site.com it shows me what I wrote as a title when I add to my website to the host. But when I write www.site.com/index.html everything is okay and it shows my website title. How can I fix it? Thanks..

Comment: Why don't you try to another browser to see if the browser has kept that data from the time that you added your website to the host. If other browsers are ok, then delete the stored data to your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook takes the relevant data to display from the og meta tags you place inside your

In example if you want to set a title you want Facebook to display you would add:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Website Title!" />
```

Also don't forget to add this:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234567890" />
```

For the content you can place your facebook_id or facebook_id of your app. It will grant you access to insights and more.

Cheers